# edit in data grid view c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

I can't able to edit the cell value of a unbound column in a data grid view . I also checked the readonly property for both gridview and individual column . And also my grid view's edit mode in "EditOnKeystrokeOrF2". Can anyone know this issue ...

I have Both Bound and Unbound Columns in the grid .

Comment: I just want to edit through keyboard ... Is there need of code

Comment: @Hogan : I mean i never used a single line of code ... i just dragged and dropped that control from toolbox ... that's it ...

Comment: You may want to read this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yztkd864.aspx

Comment: I totally agree, programming should *never* be about writing code.